# Problems positioning of h1 within divs

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm trying to position h1's within divs. Specifically, I'm trying to center them horizontally and vertically, but I'm encountering issues doing this. My code is pasted below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Hi. I'm Zack. I like to code and build things.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/ico" />
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meyer-reset.css">

        <title>Zack</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <nav>
                <ol>
                    <li id="A">About</li>
                    <li id="B">Blog</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div id="teal1">
            <h1 class="text">Zack </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="teal2">
        </div>

        <div id="teal3">
        </div>

        <div id="blue1">
        </div>

        <div id="blue2">
        </div>

        <div id="blue3">
        </div>

        <div id="purple1">
        </div>

        <div id="purple2">
        </div>

        <div id="red1">
        </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

CSS 1

```
  body {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 5px;

}

header{
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
}

header li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

ol {
    text-align: center;
}

#A {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

div {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
}

#teal1 {
    background: #1CF9D4;
}

#teal2 {
    background: #1DE4DB;
}

#teal3 {
    background: #1FD0E2;
}

#blue1 {
    background: #20BBE9;
}

#blue2 {
    background: #22A7F0;
}

#blue3 {
    background: #2392F7;
}

#purple1 {
    background: #4F87DC;
}

#purple2 {
    background: #727EC7;
}

#red1 {
    background: #DC6387;
}
```

CSS 2 (meyer reset)

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


    header li {
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    li {
        color: white;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ol {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #A {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    div {
        height: 350px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #teal1 {
        background: #1CF9D4;
    }

    #teal2 {
        background: #1DE4DB;
    }

    #teal3 {
        background: #1FD0E2;
    }

    #blue1 {
        background: #20BBE9;
    }

    #blue2 {
        background: #22A7F0;
    }

    #blue3 {
        background: #2392F7;
    }

    #purple1 {
        background: #4F87DC;
    }

    #purple2 {
        background: #727EC7;
    }

    #red1 {
        background: #DC6387;
    }
```

Comment: Too much code! Can you boil it down to a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and maybe post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Absolutely! Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EFLMa/ Sorry for the length!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fix:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;        <- made change
}
```